# Can i use RJ45 ethernet splitter as second contection to my pc?

Tags: router, ethernet, splitter, rj-45

I have a router and laptop but when my parents turn off router I will not receive the internet, so I decided to use RJ45 as the second connection. You can see how I imagined it in the picture. So, I interested before buying it will it actually work? When the router on I have internet, when the router is off I still have internet. Will this work?

[image: The picture!]

Comment: Cause they’ll never notice a second line? Seems like a bad idea. No one with WiFi nearby you could leach off of?

Comment: This is a very bad idea as, even if it works, which is unlikely, you are bypassing protections the router provides and allowing anyone on the internet to access your laptop. Do not attempt to do this.

Comment: @StarNamer: Fortunately, Windows comes with a built-in firewall blocking all incoming connections. (Which I'm sure nobody ever disables.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would not work. Usually those splitters/combiners are used for combining two 100Mbit Ethernet links via one CAT cable and splitting it to two links again. It won't split your internet connection.

Comment: The ones I have seen allow the connection to split, but both lines can’t be used at the same time

Answer (score 1):

*No*, this categorically will not work.

Besides.... presumably your parents are turning off the router for a reason? Perhaps discussing it with them would be a better idea.

---

These adapters come in a number of different variants, with different internal wiring. They are typically used to allow two connections via a single 4-pair Category cable (i.e [CAT 5e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable))

Typically:

- 2x Computers
- 1x PC + 1x Phone ([POTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service))
- 2x Phones

If you purchased the correct variant, you *could* use two of the router's LAN ports to service two computers via a single cable at up to 100 Mbit/s.

There are also variants around that will electrically connect the signals onto all ports... but they are fundamentally flawed when discussing Ethernet.

It is not possible to "*split*" or "*join*" an Ethernet (or possibly even DSL / Cable) connection like this.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that, usually the WAN port needs PPoE (or other authentication method) AND VLAN tagging to work properly. Values are usually preconfigured on the routers your ISP provides, but you would have to do this manually on your computer in order to work, even if you connect it directly without the splitter.

Just... tell your parents not to turn off the router. Power consumption of a modern router is quite low (arround 10-15W on low end devices), turning it off 12h/day barely makes a 1$/1€ savings per month. If that is still a concern, just turn off the wifi instead of the whole router. The cabled switch's power consumption is very low.